# deserializing models in play 2.2

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I've been looking at the docs at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonCombinators for the last couple of hours which has lead me to a model that looks like:

```
case class Person(
    id: Pk[Long], 
    email: String,
    isActive: Boolean,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String, 
    gender: String,
    dob: String,
    address: String, 
    phone: String)


object Person{
    implicit object PkFormat extends Format[Pk[Long]] {
        def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Pk[Long]] = JsSuccess (
            json.asOpt[Long].map(id => Id(id)).getOrElse(NotAssigned)
        )
        def writes(id: Pk[Long]): JsValue = id.map(JsNumber(_)).getOrElse(JsNull)
    }

    implicit val personFormat = (
        (__ \ "id").format[Pk[Long]] ~
        (__ \ "email").format[String] ~
        (__ \ "isActive").format[Boolean] ~
        (__ \ "firstName").format[String] ~
        (__ \ "lastName").format[String] ~
        (__ \ "gender").format[String] ~
        (__ \ "dob").formatNullable[String] ~
        (__ \ "address").formatNullable[String] ~
        (__ \ "phone").formatNullable[String] ~
    )(Person.apply, unlift(Person.unapply))
```

I'm getting a compile time error:

> type mismatch; found : (anorm.Pk[Long], String, Boolean, String, String, 
>   String, String, String, String, Long, Long, String, String) => models.Person
>   required: (anorm.Pk[Long], String, Boolean, String, String, String, 
>   Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Long, Long, Option[String],
>   Option[String]) => ? Note: implicit value personReads is not applicable here 
>   because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type

Which makes sense because String and Option[String] are not the same. I've tried adding `orElse(null)` or `getOrElse(Null)` to the optional fields but both give compile time errors about how those methods are not available on the given object.

What is the correct way to deserialize optional fiends in json? This doesn't seem maintainable compared as the number of attributes on an object grows when compared to something like Jackon with annotations.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Json.Reads` or Json.Format` to do the same? Like this: `implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]`?

Comment: Tried resulted in 
    `Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to ((<list fields>) => models.Person)`

Comment: If `dob` `address` `phone` can be null, the `Person` case should have those fields declared as `Option[String]`. It is recommended avoid using `null` in scala.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `formatNullable[A]` that means that you will get an `Option[A]`, `None` if the field is missing and `Some(a: A)` if the field is present.

In your case class you have typed `dob`, `address` and `phone` as `String` but then in your format you say `formatNullable[String]` which means that the list of values that has been parsed does not match the apply method that you have provided (`Person.apply`). The error message tells you the expected parameter list of the function given and the actual one.

Change the fields in the case class, your format or provide an intermediate function instead of `Person.apply` that provides defaults if the values are not present and creates an instance of `Person`.